# GET request with query parameters returns 403 error (signature does not match) - AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-amplify, dynamodb-queries

#### Problem

I was trying to use 'aws-amplify' GET API request **with query parameters** on the client side, but it turned out to be **Request failed with status code 403**, and the response showed:

```
"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

**Note: React.js as front-end, Javascript as back-end.**

#### My code

Front-end

```
function getData() { 
  const apiName = 'MyApiName';
  const path = '/path';
  const content = { 
     body:{
        data:'myData',
    },
  };

  return API.get(apiName, path, content);
}
```

Back-end

```
try {
      const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);

    } catch (e) {
        return failure({ status: false });
    }
```

#### What I did to debug

1. The GET lambda function works fine in Amazon Console (Tested)
2. If I change the backend lambda function so that the frontend request can be made without parameters, i.e. `return API.get(apiName, path)`, then no error shows up.

#### My question

How can I make this **GET request with query parameters** works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed GET to POST (`return API.post()`), everything works fine now.

If anyone can provide a more detailed explanation, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I don't think that's a solution at all. you just changed the REST API's method type. Did you ever find the solution to make it work with REST GET API amplify?

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary In my case here, the query parameter is in the message body instead of appending it in URL string. POST method is what I was looking for. If you want to work with GET method, the parameters should be appended in the url string. You may refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorial/Difference-between-GET-and-POST-method-in-HTTP/3916#:~:text=method%20in%20HTTP.-,Both%20GET%20and%20POST%20method%20is%20used%20to%20transfer%20data,transferring%20data%20from%20client%20to)

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary If you want to insist on using GET method, you will have to change the authorization of that method from **AWS_IAM** to **None** from Amazon API Gateway

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually did find the solution and that was an issue with the AWS Amplify's IOS SDK and they way they were interpreting my arguments (having ' : '). It's probably related to the incorrect encoding which that SDK is internally trying to encode that into. Stupid AWS!

Comment: Well, for my use case, I had a queryParameter like this:- "2021/04/23 17:23:23" and it was failing because Amplify's iOS SDK probably can't decode " : " or on some similar lines. So, I rather started sending the queryParameter as:- "20210423172323". Changed the format! But again, that's my use-case.

Comment: I just experienced the same thing. The reason why you get a 403 error is because you are not allowed to send a body along in a GET request; this is not specific to aws-amplify but is how it is in general. Instead, you are supposed to send the data in the form of query params, or, as you figured out yourself, send a post request.

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary Thre is an open issue in github for amplify-swift. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift/issues/2542